# Gather twice in same data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataframe where I want to do two separate gathers

```
library(tidyverse)
id <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
test_1_baseline <- c(1,2,4,5,6)
test_2_baseline <- c(21000, 23400, 26800,29000,30000)
test_1_followup <- c(0,4,2,3,1)
test_2_followup <- c(10000,12000,13000,15000,21000)
layout_1 <-data.frame(id,test_1_baseline,test_1_followup,test_2_baseline,test_2_followup)
```

This is the current layout.
Each person is 1 line. 
The result of Test 1 at baseline is one variable
The result of Test 2 at baseline is a second variable
The same applies to Test 1/2 follow-up results

I would like the data to be tidier. One column for timepoint, one for result of test A, one for result of test B.

```
id2 <- c("A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D","E")
time <- c(rep("baseline",5),rep("followup",5))
test_1_result <- c(1,2,4,5,6,0,4,2,3,1)
test_2_result <- c(21000, 23400, 26800,29000,30000,10000,12000,13000,15000,21000)
layout_2 <- data.frame(id2, time,test_1_result,test_2_result)
```

I'm currently doing a what seems to me odd process where first of all I gather the test 1 data

```
test_1 <-  select(layout_1,id,test_1_baseline,test_1_followup) %>%
  gather("Timepoint","test_1",c(test_1_baseline,test_1_followup)) %>% 
  mutate(Timepoint = replace(Timepoint,Timepoint=="test_1_baseline", "baseline")) %>%
  mutate(Timepoint = replace(Timepoint,Timepoint=="test_1_followup", "followup"))
```

Then I do same for test 2 and join them

```
test_2 <- select(layout_1,id,test_2_baseline,test_2_followup) %>%
  gather("Timepoint","test_2",c(test_2_baseline,test_2_followup)) %>% 
  mutate(Timepoint = replace(Timepoint,Timepoint=="test_2_baseline", "baseline")) %>%
  mutate(Timepoint = replace(Timepoint,Timepoint=="test_2_followup", "followup"))   

test_combined <- full_join(test_1,test_2)
```

I tried doing the first Gather and then the second on the same dataframe but then you end up with duplicates; i.e you end up with

1. ID 1 Test_1 Baseline Test_2 Baseline
2. ID 1 Test_1 Baseline Test_2 Followup
3. ID 1 Test_1 Followup Test_2
4. Baseline ID 1 Test_1 Followup Test_2 Followup
   == 4 rows where there should only be 2

I feel there must be a cleaner tidyverse way to do this.
Guidance welcomed

Answer (score 3):

One option with `data.table` using `melt` which can take multiple `measure` `patterns`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- unique(sub(".*_", "", names(layout_1)[-1]))
melt(setDT(layout_1), measure = patterns("test_1", "test_2"),
          value.name = c('test_1_result', 'test_2_result'), 
          variable.name = 'time')[, time := nm1[time]][]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `gather` all columns except `id`, then use `separate` to split into result and time.

Note that this code assumes that the result name is always 6 characters (`test_1`, `test_2`), and separates based on that assumption. You'll need to devise a different `separate` if that is not the case.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

layout_1 %>% 
  gather(Var, Val, -id) %>% 
  separate(Var, into = c("result", "time"), sep = 6) %>% 
  spread(result, Val) %>% 
  mutate(time = gsub("_", "", time))
```

Result:

```
   id     time test_1 test_2
1   A baseline      1  21000
2   A followup      0  10000
3   B baseline      2  23400
4   B followup      4  12000
5   C baseline      4  26800
6   C followup      2  13000
7   D baseline      5  29000
8   D followup      3  15000
9   E baseline      6  30000
10  E followup      1  21000
```